# Email check with angular

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularjs to validate an email input in a jsp page.

```
<p>Email:</p>
<input type="email" name="email1" ng-model="email1" required/>
<div class="custom-error" ng-show="loginForm.email1.$dirty && loginForm.email1.$invalid">Invalid:
<span ng-show="loginForm.email1.$error.required">Email is required.</span>
<span ng-show="loginForm.email1.$error.email">Please, write a valid email address.</span>
</div>
```

This code function, but when I put mails without .it, .com like ciccio.mario@gmail does not catch the error. How can I fix this bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-pattern to custom validation

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);


function MainCtrl() {}





angular.module("app").controller("MainCtrl", MainCtrl);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <form name="loginForm">
      <input type="email" name="email1" ng-model="email1" required ng-pattern="/\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*/" required />
      <div class="custom-error" ng-show="loginForm.email1.$dirty && loginForm.email1.$invalid">Invalid:
        <span ng-show="loginForm.email1.$error.pattern">Not a valid email!</span>
        <span ng-show="loginForm.email1.$error.required">This field is required!</span>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

</div>
```